# PHP: Easiest way to convert to "pretty numbers"?

Tags: php, math, text

I have prices that end up as:

```
3.03
8229.23
8459.39
384.29
393.20
229.99
etc
```

I want a simple function by which I can convert these to their "prettier" version. I basically want to: Round UP to either the 49.99 or 9.99 version. So the above would become:

```
3.03 --> 9.99
8229.23 --> 8249.99
8459.39 --> 8459.99
384.29 --> 399.99
393.20 --> 399.99
229.99 --> 249.99
```

I.e. Prices always end with either 9.99 or 49.99.

How would I do that in PHP?

Comment: I, as a customer, can't see why `9.99` is prettier than `3.03` ... Did you meant `2.99` ?

Comment: In USD, jumping from 2.99 to 9.99 is a lot. But for my currency, it's like changing it form .49c to .99 cents.

Comment: OK, got it. Sorry, in Euro this sounds like *hard, unleashed capitalizm*! :) However, even in your currency a good algorithm could even lower the price for some products (rising it on other products will compensate that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this (I am assuming you meant for `8459.39 --> 8499.99`:

```
$get_new_price = function($price) {
  $base = $price / 100;
  return ($base > 0.1 ? ($base - floor($base) > 0.5 ? floor($base) * 100 + 99.99 : floor($base) * 100 + 49.99) : 9.99);
};

$prices = array(
  3.03,
  8229.23,
  8459.39,
  384.29,
  393.20,
  229.99
);

$new_prices = array_map($get_new_price, $prices);
```